# Using dot-product instead of multiplying with transpose

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra, transpose, dot-product

We have the following equation, that we want to implement into our code with arrays/matrices
h(x, y, z) = ax + by + cz

pseudeo code:

```
X = [a, b, c]  
A = [x, y, z]
```

Often I see the equation being implemented like this:

```
h = transpose(A) * T
```

Is there any difference of just using the dot product?

```
h = dotproduct(A, X)
```

Is there a specific reason why the transpose is used over the dotproduct?

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, there's no difference. In implementation- `dotproduct(...)` may actually be faster, since `transpose(...)` may eagerly move the elements around prior to the matrix multiplication, doing "unnecessary" work.

Comment: Then why is everone using transpose?

Comment: @WithiWeis Could be that its sufficiently optimized that performance doesn't matter- it just boils down to user preference (either a mental model or what's happening mathematically, or what functions / methods they remember offhand). I know some languages make transposition super easy in syntax, e.g. `matrix.T`